# Apache CXF different ClassLoader Issue

Tags: soap, cxf, classloader

I'm building a SOAP WebService.
In this SOAP Webservice, I want to save the XML request to a file.

To do so, I know I can simply use a chain handler, however, I need other information that aren't transmitted in the request itself, but rather calculated in the WebService, which is why I feel like I should retrieve the MessageContext in my WebService.

Hopefully, I can use @Resource to get the WebServiceContext and retreive the Message Context. However, I can't seem to be able to cast the MessageContext to the class I want. Here is the code of my endpoint:

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext;
[...]
public MyClass [...] {
[...]
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    public WSResponse lister(SecurityInfo security, MessageId messageID, RequestBody body) { 
        if(wsContext.getMessageContext() instanceof WrappedMessageContext) { 
            //The code never goes in this
        }
        //However this : 
        wsContext.getMessageContext().getClass().toString(); //equals this : "org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext"
        //And this is where the problem is
        wsContext.getMessageContext().getClass().getClassLoader().toString(); // is : ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.apache.cxf.impl:main" [...]
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().toString(); // is : ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.my_ws_module.war:main" [...]
}
```

I didn't even know about CXF 5 days ago, and discovered classloaders yesterday, but I think I kind of understand why is this happening, however, when it comes to solving it, I'm quite clueless...

Worth noting:
The project uses Maven, Spring, CXF and Java 1.8

Comment: Basically you want xml  as string in your service right?

Comment: Yeah, that's it.
And I know how to read it from a "SoapMessage" object, wich I could extract from a WrappedMessageContext, but I can't cast the wsContext to a WrappedMessageContext because its class was loaded by a different class loader.